# KML Layers Cursor CSS - Google Maps API v3

Tags: css, google-maps, overlay, kml, google-maps-api-3

I've run into a small problem with the semi-new KML Overlay functionality with Google Maps API v3, wherein while I am able to use "suppressInfoWindows: true;", the cursor still appears as though the overlay(s) are clickable.

Is there a way at this time to change the css on the overlay(s) so that the cursor is the default cursor, so that they are purely visual, and don't confuse the user?

Comment: The link is dead. This is not a good idea to have temporary links in questions/answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this through javascript (not sure about a purely CSS solution) using something along the lines of...

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'myKmlFile.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true
});
if (ctaLayer.suppressInfoWindows) ctaLayer.setOptions({clickable:false});
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Shame it never got accepted but this answer works fine. I've not tried adding the `clickable:false` declaration to the original setup object but I'd imagine that would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. You should file it at the Google Maps API's [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles).

Comment: It's not a bug, just part of the granularity of features of the API - being clickable and having an info window are separate concerns.